# bind server the db.root file

Tags: server, root, bind

I have installed the bind server, and everything is OK.
I deleted `/etc/bind/db.root`, but bind still work and asks root server.
How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Bind uses a compile-time built in default list of root servers hints if no hint zone is specified or exists in your bind config.